# Correct specification of a nested mixed effect model in lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I have experiments where we tested 4 substances at different days. We have substance 1 tested 10 times at day 1, substance 1 tested 10 times at day 2, substance 2 tested 10 times at day 3, etc.
We see that there is a variability in the day.

I would like to model substance as a fixed effect and day as a random effect nested in substance. However, I would like to use a pooled variance estimate for the day out of the 2 tests for each substance.

If I have understood [this page](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) correctly,

```
substance + (1|substance:day)
```

would calculate a different variance for day for each substance

and

```
(1|substance/day)
```

would treat substance as random.

How can I achieve the model specification I described?

Comment: I am slightly confused as to why `(1|substance:day) ` is not what you want. In that way you i will have an intercept varying among days within the same substance group (which I think is what you want right?).

Comment: When you say that there is variability in the day, do you mean that observations appear to have *fluctuating variability* in the sense of having greater or lesser standard deviation as a function of time, or do you mean to say that the mean response appears to vary over time in such a way that the intracluster variability within a particular day exceeds the temporal differences between repeated measures drawn within a single day? Are your 10 daily measurements taken from various *sites* within a cluster, or are they drawn over time within the day (e.g. one hour apart)?